# Need to change the Tab name in through metadata

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, package, tab

I want to change custom tab name using metadata deployment.
I  have below Metadata where i have included Label but still its not reflecting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<customObject>true</customObject>
<label>Change Label</label>
<motif>Custom70: Handsaw</motif>
```

Any Help is much appriciated

Comment: What happens when you deploy it? Do you receive an error? (please [edit])

Comment: no.but tab name is not getting changed